# Why is python azure function failing to run locally?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to run a python azure function locally using VSCode but it keeps shutting itself down almost immediately.

I have created the simplest example function following the tutorial but I believe I have some configuration wrong on my machine.

Almost immediately after starting the function I see the following

```
[9/1/2019 4:52:07 PM] Found the following functions:
[9/1/2019 4:52:07 PM] Host.Functions.HttpTriggerTest
[9/1/2019 4:52:07 PM]
[9/1/2019 4:52:07 PM] Host initialized (573ms)
[9/1/2019 4:52:07 PM] Host started (590ms)
[9/1/2019 4:52:07 PM] Job host started
[9/1/2019 4:52:07 PM] python: can't open file 'C:\Users\First': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[9/1/2019 4:52:07 PM] python: can't open file 'C:\Users\First': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[9/1/2019 4:52:07 PM] Starting language worker process:python  C:\Users\First Last\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2019.3.6558\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py --default --host 127.0.0.1 --port 9091 --wait "C:\Users\First
Last\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\worker.py" --host 127.0.0.1 --port 64975 --workerId e9dc059f-128f-4e11-8363-797b4f1eeb1b --requestId c857107a-6b99-4d5a-9b71-d27827bfcad3 --grpcMaxMessageLength 134217728
[9/1/2019 4:52:07 PM] python process with Id=20920 started
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\file_location\Dev\PythonDev\MyAzureFunctions
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:7071
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

Http Functions:

        HttpTriggerTest: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTriggerTest

[9/1/2019 4:52:07 PM] python: can't open file 'C:\Users\First': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[9/1/2019 4:52:07 PM] Exceeded language worker restart retry count for runtime:python. Shutting down Functions Host
[9/1/2019 4:52:07 PM] Stopping host...
[9/1/2019 4:52:07 PM] Stopping JobHost
[9/1/2019 4:52:07 PM] Job host stopped
[9/1/2019 4:52:07 PM] Host shutdown completed.
Application is shutting down...
```

Note: the error messages call out that the file C:\Users\First can't be opened because it does not exist.  It is true that it does not exist.  What does exist is a *folder* called "C:\Users\First Last".  Perhaps the space in my windows User Name is causing an issue?

Comment: It is most likely the space. How is the path being passed to the program?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not passing it in explicitly.  I'm guessing the azure core tools is using it based on my PATH variable but I'm not sure.

Comment: Try renaming folder "First Last" to "FirstLast" (no space).

Comment: Can you show us the python code that is causing the error?

Comment: Did you still have this error?

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution ?

Comment: Yes, the answer marked as correct on this post identified the problem, my comment below that answer clarifies the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's because you put directory in single quote `''`, you need to put them in double quotes `""`. 
i.e. `"C:\Program Files\Python 3.4\python.exe"`

If this is not the key problem, please share some your code causing the problem.

Comment: This is the issue but, unfortunately, the solution doesn't work because I am not responsible for the code using that path.  That path is coming from the PATH variable and used by the azure-functions-python-worker, as confirmed by this ticket on their github https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/537

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem earlie with older versions of `python`.

#### Make sure you run the teminals or vscode as administrator while doing the below

1. What version of python are you using ?

   If you are using anything less than `3.6.8` you will have to uninstall the old version and download the latest one from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/)
2. What version of `azure-functions-core-tools` are you using ?

   Even after installing latest version of python,if your problem is'nt solved -> Try uninstalling this as well, and then `reboot` your machine - > then do `npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools`
3. Even if that did'nt work, temporarily disable **Windows Defender real-time scans**.